Plot a decision tree from HistGratientBoostingClassifier
I have a HistGradientBoostingClassifier model and I want to plot one or more of its decision trees, nevertheless I can't manage to find a native function to do it, I can access the Tree predictor objects and thus it's nodes, but in order to plot it into the sklearn.tree.plot_tree function it needs to be a DecisionTree type object
I tried this:
from sklearn.tree import plot_tree

plot_tree(RF_90._predictors[0][0])

getting this error:

InvalidParameterError: The 'decision_tree' parameter of plot_tree must
be an instance of 'sklearn.tree._classes.DecisionTreeClassifier' or an
instance of 'sklearn.tree._classes.DecisionTreeRegressor'. Got
<sklearn.ensemble._hist_gradient_boosting.predictor.TreePredictor
object at 0x7f676ebf0310> instead.

Note: RF_90 is the HistGradientBoostingClassifier fitted model

In order to visualize trees generated by HistGradientboostingClassifier this function worked for me:
def visualize_tree(tree, feature_names, class_names): 
dot = graphviz.Digraph() 
def add_nodes_edges(dot, nodes, node_id):
    node = nodes[node_id]
    if node['is_leaf']: 
        value = node['value'] 
        dot.node(str(node_id), f"Predict: {value}") 
    else: 
        feature = feature_names[node['feature_idx']] 
        threshold = node['bin_threshold'] 
        dot.node(str(node_id), f"{feature} <= {threshold:.2f}") 
        left_child = node['left'] 
        right_child = node['right']
        dot.edge(str(node_id), str(left_child), "True") 
        dot.edge(str(node_id), str(right_child), "False") 
        add_nodes_edges(dot, nodes, left_child) 
        add_nodes_edges(dot, nodes, right_child) 
nodes = tree.__getstate__()['nodes'] 
add_nodes_edges(dot, nodes, 0) 
return dot 

# Create and visualize the tree 
dot = visualize_tree(single_tree, RF_90.feature_names_in_, 1) 
dot.render("hist_gb_tree") # Save to file 
dot #view from jupyter

where RF_90 is the fitted model and single_tree is:
single_tree = trees_per_iteration[iteration][class_index]

where iteration = 0 and class_index = 0

you can use a sklearn pipeline and use the classic Gradient Boosting:
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

one_hot_encode = [
    'categorical_v1',
    'categorical_v2', 
    ...
]
# One-hot encode categorical features
ct = ColumnTransformer([
    ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'), one_hot_encode)
], remainder='passthrough')

X_encoded = ct.fit_transform(X)

# Fit the model
clf = GradientBoostingClassifier(n_estimators=10, random_state=0)
clf.fit(X_encoded, y)

and then use the plot_tree function:
plot_tree(clf.estimators_[0, 0],
    filled=True,
    feature_names=ct.get_feature_names_out(),rounded=True,
    proportion=True)

